# Why I am not able to add different variables in Console.Write()

Tags: c#

I have practiced following test and do not find a reason, why I cannot combine different kind of variables in Console.Write(), but in Console.WriteLine().

---

```
var firstName = "Bob";   //initialized as string
var inbox = 3;           //initialized as int
var degree = 34.4m;      //initialized as decimal

Console.Write("Hello, {0}", firstName);
Console.Write("! You have ");
Console.Write(inbox);
Console.Write(" in your inbox. The temperature is ");
Console.Write(degree);
Console.Write(" celsius.");

Console.WriteLine(" ");
Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}! You have {1} in your inbox. The temperature is {2} celsius.", firstName, inbox, degree);
```

---

Why is the following solution not possible?

---

```
var firstName = "Bob";   //initialized as string
var inbox = 3;           //initialized as int
var degree = 34.4m;      //initialized as decimal

Console.Write("Hello, {0}", firstName);
Console.Write("! You have {1}", inbox);
Console.Write(" in your inbox. The temperature is {2}", degree);
Console.Write(" celsius.");
```

OR

```
Console.Write("Hello, {0}! You have {1} in your inbox. The temperature is {2} celsius.", firstName, inbox, degree);
```

Comment: "Why is the following solution not possible?" - what do you mean by "not possible"? What happens when you try it? I suspect you're getting an exception - so that should be in the question.

Comment: Hint: what do you think the `{2}` in the format string `" in your inbox. The temperature is {2}"` means? I suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not possible because you should use string.Format for this purpose.
In your example it should look like this

```
Console.Write(string.Format("Hello, {0}! You have {1} in your inbox. The temperature is {2} celsius.", firstName, inbox, degree));
```

Also remember that in each string format, the numeration of fields begin from zero, so instead of your code:

```
Console.Write("Hello, {0}", firstName);
Console.Write("! You have {1}", inbox);
Console.Write(" in your inbox. The temperature is {2}", degree);
Console.Write(" celsius.");
```

You should do it like that:

```
    Console.Write(string.Format("Hello, {0}", firstName));
    Console.Write(string.Format("! You have {0}", inbox));
    Console.Write(string.Format(" in your inbox. The temperature is {0}", degree));
    Console.Write(string.Format(" celsius."));
```

It also should work.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! So that meant, Console.WriteLine() is putting everything directly in string.Format, while Console.Write() still need to be defined.

Comment: @T000sassa Console.WriteLine same as Console.Write is just putting string to console output. You have to prepare string first, and in your case string.Format is one of many ways to prepare string (there are at least 10 other solutions to do it) , that should be visible on output. So firstly string.Format will run, it will return newly created string without brackets {0}, and instead of them it will put paremeters from the list. Then Console.WriteLine will run with newly formatted string, and it will put in on console output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Format()` to acheive your required functionality.

```
Console.Write(string.Format("Hello, {0}! You have {1} in your inbox. The temperature is {2} celsius.", firstName, inbox, degree));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on the following code
[code sample](https://glot.io/snippets/g7aghkbddm)

It is not about Console.Write or Console.WriteLine

`Console.Write("Hello, {0}", firstName); Console.Write("! You have {1}", inbox);`

Here Statement 1 will work because the parameter passed 'firstName' is at 0 index
but in Statement 2, it will throw an exception as the parameter 'inbox' is at position 0 and your code tries to find parameter at position 1 which is not available.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also helpful for me to keep in mind